# The approval process references the workflow action FieldUpdate OwnershipField_Update, which doesn't exist for the Account object

Tags: deployment, approval-process, field-update

While trying to deploy an approval process I get the following error:

The approval process references the workflow action FieldUpdate OwnershipField_Update, which doesn't exist for the Account object

[image]

Comment: did you  include Workflows in your deployment package?

Comment: i have not created any workflows for this approval process

Comment: but field updates are part of the Workflow metadata type

Comment: yes ,I missed it while deploying thk u it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field Updates are part of the [Metadata Workflow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_workflow.htm?search_text=workflow) type and must be included when deploying an [Approval Process](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_approvalprocess.htm?search_text=approval%20process) that uses Field Updates

You can see this in the `ApprovalProcess` XML wherein the actions are an array of `WorkflowActionReference` per the doc

### ApprovalAction

Represents the actions that occur as a result of an approval process.

```
Field Name  Field Type                  Description
action      WorkflowActionReference[]   An array of workflow actions to execute.
```

XML example

```
...
<initialSubmissionActions>
    <action>
        <name>OwnershipField_Update</name>
        <type>FieldUpdate</type>
    </action>
    
</initialSubmissionActions>
...
```

*Side note:
If using a vendor DevOps product, such product can tell you that you are missing metadata before you deploy, thus saving time*